# Python Tkinter Button Appear at the First Window

Tags: python, tkinter

**I wanted to create a multiple windows that can go back at the first window and can open another window.**

I created a button that can transfer me to the first window but when I click the Go back Button, The Go Back Button also appear at the first window

```
       from tkinter import *



class testing:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.btn_Init(root)



    def btn_Init(self,root):
        self.btn  = Button(root, text="Go back Login",command = lambda:window(root))
        self.btn.pack()


class window:
    def __init__(self,root):
        root.config(bg='orange')
        root.geometry("500x500")

        self.btn_view = Button(root,text="View", bg='green',width=13,height=4,command =lambda:self.view_onclick(root))
        self.btn_view.place(x=130,y=220)


    def view_onclick(self,root):

        self.top = testing(Toplevel(root))
        root.withdraw()


root = Tk()
window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
class testing:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.btn_Init(root)



    def btn_Init(self,root):
        self.btn  = Button(root, text="Go back Login",command = lambda:window(root))
        self.btn.pack()
```

to

```
class testing:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.btn_Init(root)



    def btn_Init(self,root):
        self.btn  = Button(root, text="Go back Login",command = lambda:window(root) and self.btn.pack_forget())
        self.btn.pack()
```

But I think your code is very odd.

Why don't you just use `.deiconify()` and `.withdraw()`?You make it more complicated。

Comment: I'm practicing the Tkinter library. I have not Learn  yet some of the .deiconfy and .withdraw Thanks for the ans also the advice